# ArcPy - Script tool to insert shapefile in MXD does not work

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

The following script has the function of inserting shapefile in an mxd project based on a previous one.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
mxd_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
shp_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
layer_output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Test_mxd_out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

#Variables
shp_input = "hellow.shp"
layer_output = "test"

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\Test"
mxd_input = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_to_shape.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd_input)[0]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shp_input,layer_output)
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_output)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

Test_mxd_output = mxd_input.saveACopy(r"C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_a_shape2.mxd")

del shp_input
del layer_output
del mxd_input
del df
del layer
del Test_mxd_out

arcpy.AddMessage("Ended process")
```

I have made this a "script tool" and the parameters are the following:

[image]

The characteristics of the folders are as follows:

[image]

I put the parameters in the script tool:

[image]

And when executing it:

[image]

It does not carry out the mxd project that it says in the parameters nor does it follow the path that I require, but rather it stays with the values that are established in the script (instead of Mxd_to_shape_2.mxd, it does the Mxd_a_shape2.mxd).

Why does it take the values of the script if in the script tool I tell it to take other values? Are there any actions or tasks that you are not doing?

Comment: You have hard wired saveACopy to "C:\GIS\Test\Mxd_a_shape2.mxd" I think it should be your string variable `Test_mxd_out`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused between variables and the variable value (what you are getting as a parameter).
Your script should read something like this:

```
import arcpy

my_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
mxd_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
shp_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
mxd_output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

arcpy.env.workspace = my_workspace
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_input)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

lyr = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(shp_input)[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

mxd.saveACopy(mxd_output)

del mxd

arcpy.AddMessage("Ended process")
```

You can use the layer file created by the MakeFeatureLayer directly.
you are not using the workspace at all so you could also remove it from the script.